# How to show/hide dropdownlist with Material angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, dropdown

So I am using angular 8. And I have two dropdownlists. ONe with already populated data in it. And one with data that is coming from a server. But now I want to hide the one with the already populated data if the dropdown is shown with the selected data coming from the server.

With the selected data

```
      <div  class="search-select searchoptions" *ngIf="selectedSearch && hasOtherOptions(selectedSearch)">
        <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option"  [(ngModel)] = "selectedValue" >
          <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of getOtherOptions(selectedSearch)" [value]="option.apiStatus" >
            {{ option.status }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </div>
```

Witht the populated data from the server:

```
      <div   class="search-select searchoptions" *ngIf="selectedSearch && hasOtherOptions(selectedSearch)">
      <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" [(ngModel)] = "selectedValueOptie" (click)="getQrCodes()"  >
        <mat-option  *ngFor="let option of returnQrCodes$ | async " value="option.value" >
          {{ option.qrCode }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </div>
```

And I have a function that checks with option is selected:

```
 searchFor() {
    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Registratie') {
      this.filerByRegistration();
    }

    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Chat') {
      this.filterByChat();
    }
    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Inlog') {
      this.filterByInlog();
    }

    if (this.selectedSearch === 'QrCode') {
      this.filterByQrCodes();
    }

    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Doelen') {
      this.filerByChallenge();
    }
  }
```

Of course this has to be refactored. But that is for later case.

So when the option QrCode is selected the With the selected data dropdownlist has to be hidden and also vice versa. So when the option Doelen will be selected the Dropdownlist with the data from the server has to be hidden.

But how to archieve this?

THank you

Comment: *ngIf variable has to be boolean to be able to check the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `boolean` to show/hide the dropdown.

`showDropdown:boolean = false`

```
searchFor() {
    this.showDropdown = false;

    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Registratie') {
      this.filerByRegistration();
    }
    ...
}

filerByRegistration(){
  ...
  // after data is fetched
  this.showDropdown = true;
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="search-select searchoptions" *ngIf="showDropdown && selectedSearch && hasOtherOptions(selectedSearch)">
  <mat-select placeholder="Opties" name="option" [(ngModel)] = "selectedValueOptie" 
    ...
  </mat-select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answare.  why filerByRegistration? it is by Qrcode

Comment: Just took the first example from your if conditions

Comment: Not 100% because  if doelen is selected then the dropdown from the api call has to been hidden

Comment: So if doelen wil be selected then the dropdown from server has to be hidden and if qrcode will be selected then the dropdown from server has to been shown and the dropdown from doelen has to been hidden

Comment: Link isn't opening

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twxmf6 this one is opening

Comment: You need to share a working stackbiltz so that some one can directly work on it and help you

Comment: You can access it now?

Comment: And did you look at it?

Comment: It isn't working. You can see it yourself, just copy the link and open in incognito mode

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ysydhi I can open in a other browser and I am not logged in

Comment: I am getting this: Import error, can't find files:
./extended-search.component.html
./extended-search.component.scss